# Treating missing values in decision trees for prediction

Tags: missing-data, cart, rpart

I am new to decision tress, just fyi. I understand how decision tress can handle missing data when model building; like surrogate splits or multiple imputation. My question has to do with missing values when making predictions. So let's say I develop this great decision tree and it is really powerful and easy to use. So I plot the decision tree and give it to a client to follow. I copied an example below. So the client goes to use the decision tree and knows permitType. So let's say the first branch is Yes and the second is No. Great so far, but now the client runs into a problem as they do not know the initiatingOffice in some particular case. I think what this would mean is that they would predict that the class is "no plan check", with a 45% probability. Is this correct? Similarly, what if, like in the example I just gave we did not have information on initiatingOffice, but we did have info on permitSubtype. Does that not matter since we do not know which way to go on the initiatingOffice branch? Thank you

[image]